# Program in C++ to store ID and Password

Tags: c++, cin, strcmp, c++98, turbo-c++

This is a part of the program which I am required to make in Turbo C++;
Here, if I give input of id as "PLAYNOW" and pass as "PASSWORD", variable p is storing the value 0 but i isn't storing. id variable is storing some junk number at the end of PLAYNOW and I am not able to figure out why. Please help. Please ignore any header files not added and the way I have taken input of password.
Thank you!

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<process.h>

int main()
{
    char id[7],pass[8];
    cout<<"Enter id: ";
    cin.getline(id,7);
    cout<<"Enter pass: ";
    cin.getline(pass);
    char idc={"PLAYNOW"};
    char passc={"PASSWORD"};
    int i=strcmp(id,idc);
    int p=strcmp(pass,passc);

    if(i==0&&p==o)
        cout<<"Welcome. ";
    else
        exit(0);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char idc` Remember that `char` is a single character. Maybe you want `const char*` or better yet use `std::string`.

Comment: in fact it is hard to believe that this code compiles, strcmp should not accept a char as an argument

Comment: ***I am required to make in Turbo C++*** Make sure if you go into programming that you devote some time to learn on a modern `c++` compiler. Turbo c++ was good 25 years ago but that was before the `c++` standardization. A lot has changed since then.

Comment: Also do not forget about the null terminator.  If you expect the password to be password then the size of `pass` needs to be 9 to include that null terminator

Comment: I can't imagine what the compiler might do with `char idc={"PLAYNOW"};`, but I'm certain it won't do what you want. I'd try `const char* idc={"PLAYNOW"};` instead. Also allocate more space for null terminators in `id` and `pass`.

Comment: `p==o` should be `p==0`  Please try and get your code to compile.

Comment: Also, please try and get your school to use gcc or clang rather than Turbo C++.  The cost is no higher, and they compile modern C++ rather than an ancient dialect.

Comment: @Logicrat:  I'd prefer to use `const char idc[] = {"PLAYNOW"};` (it saves the memory cost of an extra pointer.)

Answer (score 2):

One problem in OP's code is the insufficient amount of memory allocated for the variables. For example, with those lines:

```
char id[7];
cin.getline(id,7);
```

The function `getline` can read and store from the input stream up to **6** chars in the **null terminated** char array `id`, but then the program has to compare that string to `PLAYNOW`, which is **7** chars long.

This leads to next problem, when [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) leaves unread chars in the stream, the failbit is set, preventing any further readings.

To fix those, even with the old standard, OP can do something like this:

```
const int ssize = 32;      // enough space to store id or password
const int ssmax = 1024;
// big value...    ^^ try  std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()  instead

char id[ssize],
     pass[ssize];

cout << "Enter id: ";
cin.getline(id, ssize);          // extract (ssize - 1) chars from input
if (  cin.fail() ) {
    cin.clear();               // if user entered more then ssize chars
    cin.ignore(ssmax, '\n');   // clear the stream
}
```

The same for `pass` (OP didn't pass 8 to the second getline, too).

Then, the declarations of the strings which contain the expected ID and password are wrong. Use those:

```
char idc[] = "PLAYNOW";
char passc[] = "PASSWORD";
```

The last lines could be rewritten too:

```
if ( strcmp(id, idc) != 0  ||  strcmp(pass, passc) != 0 )
    exit(0);

cout << "Welcome. ";
cin.get();

return 0;     // end of main()
```

BTW, I'm quite sure that [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)s belonged to C++98, so this should work too:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string id, pass;    
    std::cout << "Enter id: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, id);          
    std::cout << "Enter pass: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, pass);            

    std::string idc("PLAYNOW");
    std::string passc("PASSWORD");

    if ( idc != id  ||  passc != pass )
        exit(0);

    std::cout << "Welcome. ";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if id and pass are "PLAYNOW" and "PASSWORD", id has length is 8 , and pass has length is 9 (NULL character at end of string).

I changed as below and result print in cmd is Welcome.

```cpp
char id[8],pass[9];

...

cin.getline(id,8);

char idc[] =  "PLAYNOW" ;

char passc[] =  "PASSWORD" ;

...

cin.getline(pass,9);

...

if(i==0&&p==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, beyond numerous mistakes that I simply can't begin to list, I see that you are reading from a char stream without giving the stream size. Try:

`cin.getline(pass, 8);`

I would seriously consider using a compiler that is  a bit newer, and focusing more on readability and convention, as it's clear that there are better ways to do what is ultimately being done here. Especially with the line I pointed out, this is very ad hoc. What if the string is longer/shorter than 8 characters?